# Number of subsets without objects being adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of $20$ people who have names.

1)
How can I count the different subsets of size $3$, where the people of that subset are not allowed to be next to each other in an (alphabetically) ordered list of the complete set.

And also:

2)
How many different ways are there to divide the $20$ people into $5$ disjoint groups of people if there must be at least $2$ people in each group?

So for the first one: I think I should somehow look into different possibilities, if one is from the beginning/end of list or not.

For the second one, I have the basic idea to use how many are there without that "at least 2 one group" rule. And then just subtract those when there is $1$ or none in at least one group.  So I know that I have to apply the rule from combinatorics. ($5$ disjoint groups with at least $2$ people in each of them)

Any help would be appreciated. Hopefully its explained in an understandable way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is confusing. You have a list of just some of them that can't be together?

Comment: 20 people,list of them in alphabetical order.

Comment: Have to make groups of 3 people,but they cant be in a group together if they are on that alphabetical order "neighbors"

Comment: Find a more descriptive title.

Comment: The second one is not clear. What do you mean by "those people" ? Do you want to count all ways to form 5 disjoint groups with each group having at least 2 ?

Comment: Exactly that, i need to change description i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Part 1*

Take out the $3$ chosen people, $17$ are left with $18$ gaps, as shown below:

$\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow\bullet\large\uparrow$

Replace the chosen people in any of $\binom{18}{3}$ ways

---

Try *Part 2* yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> Given $20$ people, in how many ways can a subset of three people be selected so that no two of their names are adjacent on an alphabetically ordered list?

There are $\binom{20}{3}$ ways to select a subset of three of the twenty available people.  From these, we must exclude those subsets in which two or more people are located in adjacent positions on the alphabetically ordered list.

If we line up the people alphabetically, there are $19$ ways to pick two consecutive people on the list since the first person can occupy any position on the list save the last.  We then have $18$ choices for the third person in the subset.  Hence, there are $19 \cdot 18$ ways of selecting a subset of three of the twenty people in which at least two of them are consecutive.

If we subtract the number of three person subsets with at least people whose names are adjacent on an alphabetically ordered list from the total number of three person subsets, we will have subtracted the number of subsets in which all three people are consecutive twice, once when we select the first two  and then select the third person and once when we select the last two people and then select the first person.  There are $18$ ways of selecting a subset of three consecutive people since the first person can occupy any position in the list save the final two.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of subsets of three of the twenty people in which no two are in consecutive positions on an alphabetically ordered list is 
$$\binom{20}{3} - 19 \cdot 18 + 18$$

Answer (score 0):

*Stop telling me I should comment - see my rep first.*

1) **Hint:** First, determine the number of subsets for which your condition does not apply.
When $t_n$ is a triangular number ($t_n=1/2n(n+1)$), you could calculate it this way:
$$2*t_{20-2}-(20-2)$$
The traingular numbers each count the subsets with all 3 people next to each other and respectively the first 2 or last 2 people of the subset next to each other. Then you have to subtract the count of subsets where all 3 are n.t.e.o. as you have added them twice.

Subtract the result from the total number of subsets (which is $\binom{20}{3}$).